# Deleting a widget from QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a delete button(QPushButton) in the last column of each row of my table view. I am creating these push buttons and directly setting them in view. Since I have allocated memory dynamically I wish to free this memory but I haven't stored pointers of these buttons anywhere so I am trying to obtain the widget at the time of clean up and deleting them.

```
SDelegate* myDelegate;
myDelegate = new SDelegate();
STableModel* model = new STableModel(1, 7, this);
myWindow->tableView->setModel(model);
myWindow->tableView->setItemDelegate(myDelegate);
for(int i = 0; i < no_of_rows; ++i) {
    QPushButton* deleteButton = new QPushButton();
    myWindow->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(i, 6), deleteButton);
}
exec();

// Cleanup
for(int i = 0; i < no_of_rows; ++i) {
    // code works fine on removing this particular section
    QWidget* widget = myWindow->tableView->indexWidget(model->index(i, 6));
    if (widget)
        delete widget;
}
delete model;
delete myDelegate;
```

I am getting a crash in qt5cored.dll (Unhandled exception) and application is crashing in qcoreapplication.h at the following code:

```
#ifndef QT_NO_QOBJECT
inline bool QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event)
{  if (event) event->spont = false; return self ? self->notifyInternal(receiver, event) : false; }
```

While debugging there is no issue in deleting these widgets but code crashes afterwards at some other point. I am using QTableView and custom class for model which has inherited QAbstractTableModel.

Comment: If you properly set the parent you don't need (or want) to manually delete the widget. The parent will take care of that for you. You are probably causing a double delete here. Edit: actually remove all of your deletes in your code example you posted for the same reason!

Comment: Have you tried running under a debugger? What does the call stack look like when the exception occurs?

Comment: @drescherjm code works absolutely fine on removing delete widget statement. Since I am using new to allocate memory I thought that I need to delete it myself. How can I confirm that memory allocated to pushbuttons is freed later?

Comment: @rustyx Yes I have tried under a debugger, all the code is from different DLLs in the recent call stack and I have posted the code segment from qcoreappliation in which it crashes

Comment: @wazza This behavior is a fundamental part of qt. Read the help about QObject::~QObject: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject also http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll get back to you again if I need help again in this issue. Edit: I guess still I need to delete model and delegate. Am I right?

Comment: You don't need to be deleting anything. This is 2016. Let the compiler handle object lifetimes. Keep your objects by value, not by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Qt bug that manifests as follow: if there are any index widgets, and you invoke `setModel(nullptr)` on the view, it'll crash in an assertion on `visualRow != -1` in `qtableview.cpp:1625` (in Qt 5.6.0). Presumably this bug could be triggered when the model is being removed in some other fashion too.

But I can't reproduce it by merely destroying the model instance. So I doubt that it's relevant here unless you get the same assertion failure.

Given the style of your code, it's more likely that you have a memory bug elsewhere. If you think that the code above is crashing, you should have a self-contained test case that demonstrates the crash. Is your model or delegate to blame? Would it crash using no delegate? Would it crash using a stock model?

Your code excerpt seems to be fine, if mostly unnecessary. You could allocate the delegate and the model locally. The buttons are owned by the view: as soon as the need for the buttons goes away, such as when the model changes the row count or goes away, they will get appropriately deleted. So you don't have to delete them yourself, it's safe but completely unnecessary.

Here's an example that demonstrates that in all cases, the buttons will get disposed when the model gets destroyed or the view gets destroyed, whichever comes first. Tracking object lifetime is super simple in Qt: keep a set of objects, and remove them from the set using a functor attached to the object's `destroyed` signal. In Qt 4 you'd use a helper class with a slot.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/model-indexwidget-del-38796375
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QSet<QObject*> live;
   {
      QDialog dialog;
      QVBoxLayout layout{&dialog};
      QTableView view;
      QPushButton clear{"Clear"};
      layout.addWidget(&view);
      layout.addWidget(&clear);

      QScopedPointer<QStringListModel> model{new QStringListModel{&dialog}};
      model->setStringList(QStringList{"a", "b", "c"});
      view.setModel(model.data());
      for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i) {
         auto deleteButton = new QPushButton;
         view.setIndexWidget(model->index(i), deleteButton);
         live.insert(deleteButton);
         QObject::connect(deleteButton, &QObject::destroyed, [&](QObject* obj) {
            live.remove(obj); });
      }
      QObject::connect(&clear, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{ model.reset(); });
      dialog.exec();
      Q_ASSERT(model || live.isEmpty());
   }
   Q_ASSERT(live.isEmpty());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out [QObject::deleteLater()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) , it usually helps with issues around deleting QObjects / QWidgets.

Comment: This is the very definition of cargo cult coding. You need to be able to argument this position.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit my post with more details after I get some sleep. . . :)